# PostMan sending empty body in JSON post request to the Express server

Tags: javascript, express, post, request, postman

I sent POST request from Postman to the express server. And the body after getting parsed(using app.use(express.json());) in the express app, gets an empty body, but gets params and other things right. And it works fine in the case of GET request. The body being sent is also in JSON format selected in postman.
Postman: Version 8.0.7

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are sending the body as text and you should send it as json

Comment: Hey dany952, Thank you for answering. I am sending the body as JSON. The error still existed. I tried all the solutions on StackOverflow also. But, found that the bug exists in PostMan

Comment: @dany952 wow I really did miss that, thanks it fixed my issue !

Answer (score 0):

What I configured from the thread at github postman support thread

> (https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8455)

, is that this is a *bug in PostMan*. Try using

> **RestMan chrome extension**

for **POST request**, specifically

Answer (score 0):

for me, there was a comment after a field value . I deleted it and it worked

```
{
   "foo":"hi", // bla bla bla
   "boo": "hello"
}
```

I removed //bla bla bla